# Viewing PHP properly with my Localhost using XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, include, xampp, localhost

This is my first attempt at using a localhost while editing PHP website files (I'm a HTML girl, but have been asked to make some aesthetic changes to a PHP site).

I've installed XAMPP on my Mac already and configured it (as far as I know). MySQL Database, ProFTPD, and Apache Web Server are running. I've succeeded at viewing a simple `index.php` file from the htdocs files using `localhost/index.php`. I've placed the entire website directory (named newsite) inside the htdocs folder. When I attempt to view the website in Firefox or Safari via `localhost/newsite/index.php` I get this message in the browser:

> Warning:
>   include_once(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/inc/simplepie.inc):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/newsite/index.php on line 2

This is referring to a block of PHP at the beginning of the `index.php` document. I've checked, the `simplepie.inc` file is in file inc under file `newsite`. If I try go around it by commenting out that section of code and any related calls, the browser goes blank. Can anyone please tell me what else I need to do to just view these files via localhost?

Comment: `htdocs/inc/simplepie.inc` wouldn't be 
`htdocs/inc/newsite/simplepie.inc`!? `PHP` Does what you tell it to do .. it never makes mistakes unless you do it

Comment: what is your `include_once` code? you are looking the `simplepie.inc` in wrong place.

Comment: include_once as name suggest is used to include some file in ur document. if the file does not exist or if the path is invalid, you get that warning/error

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is simple but might be complex.  So you state:

> I've checked, the simplepie.inc file is in file inc under file
>   newsite.

And then the error states:

> Warning:
>   include_once(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/inc/simplepie.inc):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/newsite/index.php on line 2

So the error is being thrown because it is trying to read this file:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/inc/simplepie.inc
```

But it is located here:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/newsite/inc/simplepie.inc
```

What are the actual contents of that `include_once`?

Since you will probably be moving this site from one place to another, I recommend doing this.  I am assuming I know what your `include_once` looks like, but the general concept holds true.

First, in your `index.php` or main config/init file (if you have one) add this line:

```
$BASE_PATH='/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/newsite';
```

Then for your `include_once` change it to read:

```
include_once($BASE_PATH . '/inc/simplepie.inc');
```

Basically that will do the equivalent of changing the `include_once` to this:

```
include_once('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/newsite/inc/simplepie.inc');
```

But the flexibility of using `$BASE_PATH` is it allows you to change the general site `$BASE_PATH` in one place & then use it wherever in your site you wish.